# Pass Gulp argument in command

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-sass

I am just wondering if it is possible to pass arguments within Gulp commands.

For example I would like to use the following command:

```
gulp alpha
```

I'd then like the `alpha` part of that command to be passed to my styles task like so:

```
gulp.task('styles', ([ ALPHA ARGUMENT HERE ]) => {
    return gulp.src('src/styles/theme/[ ALPHA ARGUMENT HERE ]/main.scss')
        .pipe(sassGlob())
        .pipe(sass({
            style: 'expanded',
            quiet: true,
            'default-encoding': 'UTF-8'
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
        //.pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(rename('[ ALPHA ARGUMENT HERE ]-all.min.css'))
        .pipe(minifycss({
          compatibility: 'ie8',
          noAdvanced: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/'));
});
```

Then when I run the default Gulp task:

```
// Default Task Init

gulp.task('default', () => {
    gulp.start('production');
});

gulp.task('production', ['clean'], () => {
    gulp.start('styles', 'images', 'fonts', 'scripts');
});
```

I'd like my styles task to have generated a file named: `alpha-all.min.css` in my `public/css/` folder.

I am currently using [Gulp Yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) to directly use tasks within the command line.

Is this possible within Gulp?

Comment: Not possible. `gulp alpha` tells gulp to run a task named `alpha`, not to run the `default` task with a parameter `alpha`. There's no way to circumvent that.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung, I managed to do this using Yargs, not perfect but works :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this myself, if anybody would like to know how to do this I used the following task:

```
var theme = argv.destination;

gulp.task('styles', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/styles/theme/' + theme + '/main.scss')
        .pipe(sassGlob())
        .pipe(sass({
            style: 'expanded',
            quiet: true,
            'default-encoding': 'UTF-8'
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
        //.pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(rename(theme + '-all.min.css'))
        .pipe(minifycss({
          compatibility: 'ie8',
          noAdvanced: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/'));
});
```

By using Gulp Yargs it I am able to pass an argument using `gulp --destination=alpha`.